# How to make a log of terminal output?

Tags: logging, ssh, terminal

I am using client laptop and ssh connection to server. I want to command heavy computation so after I type command in my client, I won't be sitting and looking at the output. As I am moving around, ssh connection breaks often so I just want all my terminal output stored in a log file. Eventually, I just need to check `test.log` if the computation is done or not in any place using my laptop.

```
something.sh > test.log
```

only caputures  `echo "message"` of `something.sh`.

But in case error occurs, error content shown on terminal isn't captured in `test.log`.

Also,

```
 script test.log
 exit
```

won't help my case because I am moving around. I can't exit the recording.

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `something.sh 2>&1 > test.log`  to capture standard out AND standard error?

Comment: `something.sh 2>&1 | tee test.log` worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, you can combine `script` and [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), running `script` inside a `screen` session.  You can detach from the `screen` session and later reattach to check progress.